# SQL WHERE condition, why the result using 'a != 7 and b !=836' is not equal ' !(a=7 and b=836)'?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

There are three records like:

- a=7 , b=836
- a=8 , b=836
- a=7 , b=839

I want to get the result without (a=7 and b=836).

the result is empty when execute the sql like `select * from test where a!=7 and b!=836`,
but it got the correct result by using `select * from test where a<>7 or b<>836`.

I have two questions:

1. Why 'a!=7 and b!=836' not equal !(a=7 and b=836)?
2. What's the different between the two conditions ?
   'a!=7 and b!=836' and 'a<>7 or b<>836'

Comment: Difference between AND / OR. These are different logical operators.

Comment: In != condition use use AND operator and in <> use OR operator . please make correct first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in your logic operators, `and` and `or`, in combination with parentheses.

`select * from test where a!=7 and b!=836`

This query would select where BOTH of your statements return true, that is both a is not 7, and b is not 836. This would return nothing, there is no record where both of these are true.

`select * from test where !(a=7 and b=836)`

When you put the parentheses around your `and`, you move the logic around. That statement means that all records NOT matching any record where both a is 7 and b is 836. So inside the parenthesis it matches the first record, then it inverts that selection.

`select * from test where a<>7 or b<>836`

The `<>` is the same as `!=` [(Link to documentation)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal). But in this query you use `or`. So it will match any record where a is not 7, AND any record that is not 836. So would match both second and third row.

For more reading material, take a look at the [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). `!(a and b)` equals `!a or !b`. More explanation [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-is-an-intuitive-way-to-explain-and-understand-de-morgans-law).

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/840315/appl3r for edits with more reading.

Answer (score -1):

Actually != and <> exactly the same. See the documentation.

`<>` is sql standard, `!=` non-standard.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal